# validate email using server request and ignore modify

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code which sends a request to server validate if the email already exists or not. Its working fine, but the problem is I am using the same directive on modify page. On modify page I want to send another param to server to ignore this email.

```
.directive('uniqueEmail', function($http) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
                var ignoreEmail= //here I want to save originol email;
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/MY/system/users/checkEmail?'+ $.param({'emailAddress': ele.val(), 'ignoreEmail': ignoreEmail})
                    }).success(function(isUnique,status,headers,cfg) {
                            var iu = isUnique == 'true' ? true : false;
                            c.$setValidity('unique', iu);
                        }).error(function(data,status,headers,cfg) {
                            c.$setValidity('unique', false);
                        });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I get the the origonal email in ignoreEmail so that can send to the server

Comment: Just save/remember it once `var ignoreEmail=ele.val();`

Comment: at that point ele.val() is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $eval:

```
var ignoreEmail = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do inside the link function is to save the initial model value, which you can get using `ngModelController`

`var ignoreMail=c.$modelValue;`

Now you have the original model value when the link function is called first time.

I have not tried it but it should work.